# How do I determine what assembly a namespace is in?

Tags: c#, mono, assemblies, namespaces, monodevelop

<s>The MSDN documentation doesn't generally specify the assembly a namespace is in, so there's no easy way to add the necessary assembly reference.</s>

NOTE: I am using MonoDevelop, so *right-click, resolve* is not an option.

Comment: Minor correction: right-click, resolve *does* exist in MonoDevelop 2.2+, but it only resolves types from referenced assemblies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424(VS.100).aspx

> Task(Of TResult) Class
>
> Represents an asynchronous operation
>   that can return a value.
>
> Namespace:  System.Threading.Tasks
>
> Assembly:  mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)

Namespaces can cross multiple assemblies, so you need to look for the assembly a specific class is in.