# How to (easily) find the proper assembly for a given namespace

Tags: .net, assemblies

I have some problems with some attributes. I can't find the proper assembly. I can't find them on google either:

```
 [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.None)]
```

In [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-1-introduction-and-model.aspx) code the following namespaces are declared:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Database;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
```

Where can I find the assemblies for these namespaces? Isn't there an easy way to find the assembly besides searching for the namespace on Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In case you have the assembly referenced:**

- Go to declaration. (`F12` in Visual Studio when cursor is on the definition you are searching for.)
- The *Object Browser* should pop up. At the root of the tree you can see the assembly.

**When you did not reference the assembly:**

- You can still use the *Object Browser* to search for your assembly (*View -> Object Browser*).
- In the dropdown box, select *"All Components"*, ... and search.

**When the classes you are looking for aren't from microsoft:**

It seems the classes you are looking for aren't from microsoft. In this case you can create a 'custom component set' in the *Object Browser*. You can add all third party assemblies there you want to search through. Lastly, if you don't have the assemblies themselves, I guess all there is left to do is Google.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all `System.Data.*` references from the project, add the `EntityFramework` reference, the option is `DatabaseGeneratedOption` (not `DatabaseGenerationOption`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `namespace` is not first class citizen in CLR. namespace + class name constitutes the full class name. So it is just a common prefix. Obvious conclusion is that namespace can be distributed across different assemblies. You can try by loading assemblies one by one and examining each type's full name for prefix (StartsWith) that will be the namespace name you are trying to find.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is a little bit late, but I got stuck with the same issue, this is what I did to fix it:

1. Install the latest version of the Entity Framework, following the instruction at:
   http://nuget.org/packages/entityframework
2. For some reason they changed the name of the property, instead of **DatabaseGenerationOption** 

   change it for **DatabaseGeneratedOption**

And it works.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.aspx), most if not all classes from this namespace are in System.Data.Entity.Design.dll, so I believe it should be this.

All MSDN doc pages mention namespace and assembly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, I'm afraid I don't know any better answer than Google, or MSDN if it's a Microsoft thing.

The problem is compounded by that fact that a given namespace can be declared in more than one assembly. And conversely, an assembly can declaremore than one namespace.

Note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754220/how-do-i-determine-what-assembly-a-namespace-is-in) question is pretty much a duplicate of the part of your question that I'm answering.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your solution add this namespace resolution:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```